# Why actual bytes read from server's response less than the Content-Length?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm writing a proxy in C in Linux 3.0 kernel. The proxy forwards the request from browser to the target server and read response from server.

This is one request:

```
GET http://www.yongchuan.org/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yongchuan.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

This is one response the proxy read:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 3170
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Location: http://www.yongchuan.org/index.html
Last-Modified: Fri, 22 Jul 2011 01:28:50 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "72d9d7b5e48cc1:1a73"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 04 Mar 2012 16:26:05 GMT

<html>

<head>

..............

<tr> 
  <td width="43%" ></td>
  <td width="46%"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="43%"><img src="images/triangle.gif"> ��ѧ�ڿγ̣�<a href="jiangyi/yytl/2007(a)/yytl.htm">Ӧ��ͼ��</a></td>
  <td width="46%" ><img src=
```

The problem is, the actual size of bytes the proxy read is 2880 and the data ends up suddenly, much less than Context length: 3170.

My code is as below:

```
241 int readlen;
242 char buffer[128 * 4096];
243 do { 
244     readlen = read(servfd, buffer, 128 * 4096);
245     printf("readlen:%d\n", readlen);
246     if( readlen < 0 ) {
247         perror("read() from server failed");
248     }   
249     printf("read content:\n%s", buffer2);
250     write(cliefd, buffer, readlen);
251 } while( readlen == 128 * 4096 );
```

Here servfd is the socket to server, cliefd is the socket to client.
What's the possible reason? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are writing your proxy not *in kernel 3.0* but **for** the kernel 3.0; your proxy is a user-level application running outside of the kernel (and issuing system calls to the kernel from time to time).. It would be crazy to code a proxy *inside* the Linux kernel (e.g. as a monster module); a good advice when considering adding code *inside* the kernel is: don't!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> while( readlen == 128 * 4096 );
> ```

The while condition is wrong. You should be checking `readlen > 0` instead.

There's no requirement that `read` only hands you completely filled buffers. In the worst case (highly unlikely with current TCP stacks), it could hand you the bytes one by one.

At any rate, if the server doesn't close the connection after delivering the output you must keep reading until you get the `Content-Length` you were promised.

Comment: I modify to while(readlen == 0) but still ends at 2880 bytes. Some ppl said it might be the problem of Proxy-Connection: keep-alive, and need to change to Proxy-Connection: close. Haven't tried that. Is it possible?

Comment: *I modify to while(readlen == 0) but still ends at 2880 bytes* Why did you do that ?

Comment: I found out it could work, just very slow, every connection to the server idles for a while, then receives a part of data, then closes. Then a new connection starts to receive the rest, and so on.

Comment: What you are supposed to do is retrieve the actual `Content-Length` value and then keep reading, regardless of buffer sizes you choose to use, until the specified number of bytes has been read. You are not doing that in the code you showed.